# Blank emails from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, email

I just released an update to my app DreamFX Photo, and made it free. My problem is that I have an "email me" button for support, and I'm getting around 3 blank emails an hour from different people.  Any thoughts if this is spam or some sort of bug?

Comment: What happens when you try this feature yourself? Is there a cancel button? What happens when you hit cancel?

Comment: No emails get sent when I try the app, even when I press the email button, then cancel. Also this didn't happen before I made my app free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

haha, i have that issue as well.

I believe users are pressing on the support link, and then decide to cancel the email. by mistake they are clicking on the "Send" button, instead of the "Cancel".

either that, or they save the email as draft and then send it later on by mistake.

Comment: +1 I concur. I have a similar issue, and the source is the same.

Comment: Same issue here.  I think people are scared of the red "delete draft" button.

Answer (score 1):

I support a very popular free app and we get tons of blank emails. We thought that it was a bug or a spam as well but after analyzing them and responding to all of them, we have come to the conclusion that there are 4 primary causes.

1. People tap the support link and then accidentally hit "send" instead of "cancel".
2. People are just tapping things randomly trying things out.
3. "Pocket emails". Similar to pocket dials, the phone becomes unlocked and unintended actions occur.
4. "Baby emails". We respond to each email, even the blank ones, and have found that often someone let their child play with the device and the child manages to send an email. This might even be our primary driver of blank emails. :)